# Not recieving android firebase notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have already set up my project with firebase and its modules, the following are the gradle codes for Project and Module level respectively

build.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }

}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version "4.3.15" apply false
}
```

build.gradle (Module)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}


android {
    namespace 'com.example.sfawebview'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sfawebview"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:filament-android:1.17.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.1")
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-ktx'
}
```

Lastly, this is the MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt file that I created for this project

```
package com.example.sfawebview

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage

const val channelId = "notification_channel"

class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        // Handle the new token here if needed
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {
            showNotification(
                remoteMessage.notification!!.title!!,
                remoteMessage.notification!!.body!!
            )
        }
    }

    private fun getCustomDesign(title: String, message: String): RemoteViews {
        val remoteView = RemoteViews(
            "com.example.sfawebview",
            R.layout.notification_main
        )

        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title)
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.message, message)
        remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.app_logo, R.drawable.sweatfree_logo_round)

        return remoteView
    }

    @SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag")
    private fun showNotification(title: String, message: String) {

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
        )

        var builder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            applicationContext,
            channelId
        )
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sweatfree_logo_round)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        builder = builder.setContent(getCustomDesign(title, message))

        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel =
                NotificationChannel(channelId, "Sweat Free", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build())
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, even with the Updated AndroidManifest file, I am not getting a notification. Whenever I launch a new cloud message campaign, it displays 'sent', however, I get no notification from my end.

I have created the required MyFirebaseMessagingService file, alongside permissions in MainActivity. My AndroidManifest has both

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />`

and

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I expect a notification to be shown while the app is running and in background. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the answer was trivial.

Android notifications through Firebase do not get shown on devices that do not have Google play services. Therefore, most emulators do not work.

This is because firebase messaging requires google play services to function.